# JSON data has concatenated field name into value field (Django)

Tags: javascript, json, django

I'm trying to return a string with JSON, Django and Ajax, however for some reason they queryset is causing the JSON to incorporate the field names as well. For example, instead of returning only the value of the field, it returns the [{'field_name': value}] as an entire string. In console, it prints out: {'field_name': "[{'field_name': value}]"}

The code I've written is:

```
def drugsanddoses(request):
    drugIdentifier = request.POST.get('drugID')

    drug_group = Antiepileptics.objects.get(name=drugIdentifier)
    drug_name = RiskCalculator.objects.filter(drug_name=drug_group).values('drug_name')
    l_dose = RiskCalculator.objects.filter(drug_name=drug_group).values('l_dose')   
    h_dose = RiskCalculator.objects.filter(drug_name=drug_group).values('h_dose')   
    pubmed_id = RiskCalculator.objects.filter(drug_name=drug_group).values('pubmed_id') 
    updated = RiskCalculator.objects.filter(drug_name=drug_group).values('updated') 

    data = {}

    try:
        data['drug_name'] = str(drug_name)
        data['l_dose'] = str(l_dose)
        data['h_dose'] = str(h_dose)
        data['pubmed_id'] = str(pubmed_id)
        data['updated'] = str(updated)

    except:
        raise Http404

    print(data)

    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the expected behavior, because you are doing `str(queryset)` on a `values()` of a query. The `values` in ORM would return a list of dict. If you only want values, do:

```
RiskCalculator.objects.filter(drug_name=drug_group) \
                      .values_list('drug_name', flat=True).distinct()
```

Django doc for [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values) and [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).

Even with that, it doesn't make sense to do `str()` on each query, you don't need `str()` at all. Because you need to serialize the whole python data structure into json. Otherwise you would have a hard time converting a string into a list of values in javascript.

Comment: Ok, that works. But where should I add the serialization then?

Comment: `JsonResponse` is doing that, so no extra work for you. Just make sure all fields are json serializable, i.e. string, numbers but not objects like foreign keys, many to many etc.

Comment: That's odd, because I implemented the following:
`drug_name = RiskCalculator.objects.filter(drug_name=drug_group).values_list('drug_name', flat=True).distinct()
data['drug_name'] = drug_name`
And I get "TypeError: [1] is not JSON serializable"

Comment: I've already mentioned in my last comment, you should make sure the result is json serializable. Please read it again and see if that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that they're all either strings or integers already (in the model they're IntegerFields or CharFields)

Comment: `values_list` doesn't return a list, it returns something called `ValuesListQuerySet`, and that's not json serializable. You need to do `data['drug_name'] = list(drug_name)` to convert it to a python list then serialize it.